# jquery add column and sum/total the table column

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I’ve searched and consulted a lot of code but nothing is helping me to fix my problem.

What I have is just "add rows", but I want also the sum after adding the rows.

Here is a part of my code that adds a row to a table:

###### Code for adding rows

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".add-row").click(function () {
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var markup = "<tr><td style='text-align:center'><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td>" + email + "</td><td  class='sum_me' style='text-align: right;'>" + name + "</td></tr>";
        $("table tbody").append(markup);
    });
});
```

###### Html

```html
<table id="countit">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width=50px>Delete</th>
            <th width=150px style="text-align: center;">Inpayment of:</th>
            <th width=50px style="text-align: center;">AMOUNT :</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" class="btn-success" value="Save Transaction" style="width: 150px; float: right;">
     
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: What is not working with the given code? What have you tried to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function that sums the values and shows the result.  call it after adding the row to the table.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

        function updateSum(){
            var sum = 0;
            $('.sum_me').each(function(item, index){
               sum = sum + $(item).text();
            });
            $('#total').text(sum);
        }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".add-row").click(function(){
            var name = $("#name").val(); // input text
            var email = $("#email").val(); // input text
            var markup = "<tr><td style='text-align:center'><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td>" + email + "</td><td  class='sum_me' style='text-align: right;'>" + name + "</td></tr>";
            $("table tbody").append(markup); 
            updateSum();
        });
    });    
</script>
```

You can use `tfooter` after the `tbody` to hold this total value

```
<table id="countit">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width=50px>Delete</th>
                <th width=150px style="text-align: center;">Inpayment of:</th>
                <th width=50px style="text-align: center;">AMOUNT :</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
             <tr><td></td><td></td><td id="total"></td></tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <input type="button" class="btn-success" value="Save Transaction" style="width: 150px; float: right;">
```

Comment: sir can you check my code and correct it please. i can't figure it out. been tryn for hours now

Comment: I have updated my answer. `updateSum()` is defined outside the callback. Its just called after row is added. Also modified the html to statically add the footer of the table. The third td have `id="total"` to make it easy to reference on `updateSum()`

Comment: its Working Now. thanksss, Thank you very Much @Gabriel A. Lopez Lopez

Comment: Perfect, please mark the answer as correct for others to easily find help. And if you consider, vote it up. Thanks